# search tag attribute value based on child node value using XmlStarlet

Tags: xml, shell, xmlstarlet

I have a xml file having structure something like below `input.xml`:

```xml
<myxml>
    <role name="test" pattern=".*">
        <assignedSIDs>
            <sid>abc</sid>
            <sid>cde</sid>
            <sid>def</sid>
        </assignedSIDs>
    </role>

    <role name="test1" pattern=".*">
        <assignedSIDs>
            <sid>abc</sid>
            <sid>zxc</sid>
            <sid>vbn</sid>
        </assignedSIDs>
    </role>

    <role name="test2" pattern=".*">
        <assignedSIDs>
            <sid>abc</sid>
            <sid>hex</sid>
            <sid>oct</sid>
        </assignedSIDs>
    </role>
</myxml>
```

I want to find `role` tag name attribute based on value of `sid` tag.
for eg: if I search for `abc`, the query must return test, `test1` and `test2`

I referred to this below link and got half of the solution:
[XMLStarlet Return attribute based on value (Reverse lookup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759220/xmlstarlet-return-attribute-based-on-value-reverse-lookup)

I also referred to this too:
http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html

but I didn't got any example that would support my requirement.

Is there something I can do?

Comment: thanks Felipe for editing the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XPath expression you can use is:
`//role[.//sid = 'abc']/@name`

The command line for xmlstarlet is:

```
C:\> xmled.exe sel -t -v "//role[.//sid = 'abc']/@name" input.xml
test
test1
test2
```

(I think it depends on your command line shell which quote character you need to use to wrap the XPath expression).

Comment: Thanks @Martin for your answer. It tried your xpath expression.. but it gave me only "test" and not "test1" and "test2" . Could you please confirm.

Comment: When I try the XPath I posted with xmlstarlet on Windows with the command line I posted it outputs `test
test1
test2`.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hudson>
 <authorizationStrategy>
  <roleMap type="globalRoles">
   <role name="Employee">
    <assignedSIDs>
     <sid>abc</sid>
    </assignedSIDs>
   </role>
  </roleMap>
  <roleMap type="projectRoles"> 
   <role name="test1">
    <permissions/>
    <assignedSIDs>
     <sid>abc</sid>
    </assignedSIDs>
   </role>
          <role name="test2">
               <assignedSIDs>
                    <sid>abc</sid>
               </assignedSIDs>
          </role>
  </roleMap>
 </authorizationStrategy>
</hudson>

Comment: Please copy the above xml lines.  This is the structure of my xml file. there are two types of tag, one is of global role and another is of project role. i want to find the user in both tags and want the role tag attribute name.

Comment: If you have a new question then start a new one. If that code in the comment is supposed to be added to your original question then edit the question and add the sample there with proper formatting. But I have posted my XPath suggestion together with a command line for xmlstarlet, I am not sure what else to do. Maybe someone else can help you further if you explain which problem you still have.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I'll remember that. Could you please give me some reference from where i can get some examples on XPATH expression using XmlStarlet

Answer (score 0):

Even though the XPATH given by @martin-honnen was correct, i was not getting the expected output. This was due to old version of xmlstarlet 1.0.1 that was installed in my system. As I upgraded to 1.6.1, problem was solved. 
here is the link, where  @kjhughes helped me to find the solution
[xmlstarlet XPath expression selects single result rather than multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33079965/xpath-expression-to-get-tag-attribute-value/33080267?noredirect=1#comment53983738_33080267)